# Encore moins (d') attention

Tags: prépositions

Bonjour,

X se trouve dans une réunion.

> Il ne prête pas attention au discours du directeur.
>
> Il prête **encore moins** attention aux discours de ses collègues. (*)

Je pense que la phrase (*) est correcte, mais j'ai des doutes. Peut-être qu'il faut écrire *encore moins **d**'attention* ?

Pourriez-vous me dire quelle variante est correcte ?

Merci

Comment: On prète quelque chose qu'non possède à quelqu'un. On peut encore dire : Il ne prête pas **son** attention au discours du directeur.

Comment: @user10191234 "prêter attention" est correct, vous pouvez trouvez des exemples dans des dictionnaires en ligne. Par exemple, _Ne prêta pas attention au présentoir à journaux ni au téléphone Bell installé sur le mur de briques rouges._ François Désalliers, _l’Homme-Café_

Comment: @jlliagre Est-ce que vous souhaitez que je commence tous les titres par une majuscule, même ceux qui ne forment pas de phrase ?

Comment: Ce n'est pas spécialement moi qui le souhaite mais les règles typographiques du français. Une majuscule est toujours requise pour la première lettre du premier mot d'une phrase. Un titre est aussi une phrase, même si elle peut être averbale. Une contrainte que n'a pas un titre est la présence d'une ponctuation finale.

Comment: Un autre conseil, StackExchange n'étant pas un forum de discussion, les bonjours et les mercis ne sont pas attendus/utiles dans les questions.  Voir https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts et aussi [Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)

Comment: 1. À mon avis, la logique d'un titre comme _How could I say “Okay? What's your point?” in French?_ est différente de celle  _sortir sur / sortir dans_ et celui-ci peut s'écrire sans majuscule. Je dirais même qu'il est préférable de ne pas la mettre pour la cohérence.

Comment: 2. Quand même... C'est plus poli et beaucoup plus agréable selon moi. Mais aucun problème, je ne vous remercierai plus dans mes commentaires :)

Comment: _pour la première lettre du premier mot d'une **phrase**._ --- Justement, il ne s'agit pas d'une phrase (sortir sur / sortir dans)

Comment: N'oublie pas l'arobase+pseudo quand tu t'adresses à quelqu'un qui n'est pas l'auteur de la question ou de la réponse. Je n'avais pas vu tes réponses à mes commentaires. 1. En français, toute [suite de mots ayant un sens](https://uoh.fr/document/a5a71f40/b9c5/4231/a5a71f40-b9c5-4231-a9e8-2cbdfb3fb170/co/02_01_definition.html) est une phrase. 2. On peut bien sûr remercier dans les commentaires, la politique de StackExchange ne concerne que les questions et les réponses (do not use greetings). Pour les discussions, il y a aussi le [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La locution « prêter attention » est une locution figée à un degré relatif. Elle se trouve dans sa forme la plus simple sans article.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pr%C3%AAter) b) [Dans des loc. indiquant que l'on accorde de l'attention, de l'intérêt à qqn, à qqc.]
> − **Prêter attention/attention + déterm.**
> ♦ Un enfant qui rit intérieurement de son professeur tout en paraissant lui prêter la plus grande attention (Balzac,E. Grandet, 1834, p.134).
> ♦ Marat mangeait rapidement, sans prêter grande attention à ce qu'il avalait (Vailland, Drôle de jeu, 1945, p.38).

Si la forme « prêter **d**'attention » était reconnue comme significative elle aurait probablement été jointe à la forme ci-dessus dans le dictionnaire. Cela est confirmé par cet [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pr%C3%AAter++attention%2Cpr%C3%AAter+d%27attention&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpr%C3%AAter%20attention%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpr%C3%AAter%20d%27%20attention%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpr%C3%AAter%20attention%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpr%C3%AAter%20d%27%20attention%3B%2Cc0) qui montre que la forme avec « de » a toujours représenté une proportion négligeable.
On voit que l'introduction de modifieurs se fait sur le modèle de la forme initiale (pas de « de ») : « prêter grande attention ». Si l'article « la » est utilisé dans le premier exemple c'est parce qu'il n'y pas d'autre moyen d'exprimer un superlatif absolu. La nature grammaticale de « de » dans ce contexte n'est pas claire puisque l'on s'attend à « de la » (« de l' » comme une voyelle suit), ce qui fait de « de » une préposition, et cela n'a pas de sens.

- Ils leur ont prêté si peu attention qu'ils sont partis sans les avertir.
- Il avait permis qu'ils parlent plus longtemps et avait gardé un enregistrement ; pour leur avoir prêté autant attention il n'en était pas plus avancé sur ce qu'ils voulaient vraiment.
- Elle lui a prêté si peu attention qu'elle ne se rappelait même pas de son nom.
- Il prête encore moins attention aux discours de ses collègues.

On ne trouve pas « si peu prêté d'attention » mais on trouve facilement « [si peu prêté attention](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=si+peu+pr%C3%AAt%C3%A9+attention%2Csi+peu+pr%C3%AAt%C3%A9+d%27attention&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csi%20peu%20pr%C3%AAt%C3%A9%20attention%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csi%20peu%20pr%C3%AAt%C3%A9%20attention%3B%2Cc0) ».
On trouve néanmoins « [prêter si peu d'attention](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pr%C3%AAter+si+peu+attention%2Cpr%C3%AAter+si+peu+d%27attention&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpr%C3%AAter%20si%20peu%20d%27%20attention%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpr%C3%AAter%20si%20peu%20d%27%20attention%3B%2Cc0) » et pas « prêter si peu attention  », ce qui montre que l'insertion d'un modifieur entraine une perte de la notion de la forme de base. Il faudrait conserver  « prêter si peu attention  » et considérer « prêter si peu d'attention  » comme incorrect.
On peut faire une remarque similaire pour « [prêter autant attention](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pr%C3%AAter+autant+attention%2Cpr%C3%AAter+autant+d%27attention&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpr%C3%AAter%20autant%20attention%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpr%C3%AAter%20autant%20d%27%20attention%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpr%C3%AAter%20autant%20attention%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpr%C3%AAter%20autant%20d%27%20attention%3B%2Cc0), prêter autant d'attention », avec la différence que dans ce cas on trouve une quantité appréciable de la forme escomptée.
Encore une fois, la forme « moins prêté d'attention » ne se trouve pas alors que
« [moins prêté attention](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pr%C3%AAt%C3%A9+moins+attention%2Cpr%C3%AAt%C3%A9+moins+d%27attention%2Cmoins+pr%C3%AAt%C3%A9+attention%2Cmoins+pr%C3%AAt%C3%A9+d%27attention&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpr%C3%AAt%C3%A9%20moins%20d%27%20attention%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmoins%20pr%C3%AAt%C3%A9%20attention%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpr%C3%AAt%C3%A9%20moins%20d%27%20attention%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmoins%20pr%C3%AAt%C3%A9%20attention%3B%2Cc0) » a une fréquence importante. La forme « prêter moins attention » ne se trouve pas à cause de a tendance à placer le modifieur avant.

La forme « prêter encore moins attention » est sans aucun doute correcte et la forme avec « de » est à éviter, même si on trouve quelques fois cette dernière dans les livres (elle ne se trouve pas autant).

---

*Addition en réponse à des [commentaires](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44223/encore-moins-attention-encore-moins-dattention/44247?noredirect=1#comment90035_44247)*
(*Si on trouve "prêter si peu d'attention" et non "prêter si peu attention", il est logique de supposer que "prêter moins attention" doive s'écrire avec un "d", "moins d'", à cause de "moins". D'ailleurs, sur ngram, il y a beaucoup plus de résultats contenant "prêter moins d'attention".

La forme « prêter encore moins attention » est sans aucun doute correcte et la forme avec « de » est à éviter --- Je le pense aussi, pourtant il y a plus de résultats avec "prêter moins d'attention".*)

Vous remarquerez que sur cet [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pr%C3%AAter+moins+attention%2Cpr%C3%AAter+moins+d%27attention&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpr%C3%AAter%20moins%20attention%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpr%C3%AAter%20moins%20d%27%20attention%3B%2Cc0) (celui que vous fournissez), jusqu'à à peu près 1920, la forme sans « de » est pratiquement inexistante. Si on regarde la forme avec « de » de plus près, on n'a pas deux choix dans la determination grammaticale de « de » : on doit considérer « de » comme étant une préposition. On aurait tendance à confondre « de » avec la forme négative du partitif, en d'autres mots, tendance à reconnaitre à « de » l'effet du partitif. Ce n'est pas une fonction que  puisse avoir ce mot dans ce contexte sémantique particulier.

- *partitif en contexte affirmatif/négatif* — Il veut **du** pain./Il ne veut pas **de** pain. — Cela demande **de l**'attention./Cela ne demande pas **d**'attention.
- *exception* — Il ne veut pas **du** pain mais du gâteau. — Cela ne demande pas **de l**'attention mais **de la** bonne volonté.

La forme « **d**' » doit donc être la préposition « de », ce qui est en contradiction avec la nature grammaticale de « prêter » ([emploi transitif direct](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pr%C3%AAter)). Comment la forme « prêter **d**'attention » a été introduite dans le langage est un mystère, peut-être à partir d'un  « prêter de l'attention » initial (figuratif, et partitif assez naturel), qui sous l'influence du contexte négatif (« ne pas prêter **d**'attention »), un contexte peut-être plus courant en moyenne que dans le cas des autres expressions (vu l'effort inhabituel demandé du référent du sujet), aurait été transformé en « prêter d'attention ».
Quoi qu'il en soit, le fait qu'à partir de 1920 lui est substitué la forme sans « de », et que, de plus, le TLFi ne la reconnaisse pas, tend fortement à vérifier que ce n'est pas une forme grammaticalement justifiable.

On peut maintenant s'intéresser à la première contention (Si on trouve « prêter si peu **d**'attention » et non « prêter si peu attention », il est logique de supposer que « prêter moins attention » doive s'écrire avec un « d », (« moins  d' », à cause de « moins ».). Ce n'est pas un cas de déduction logique, ce que je vais essayer de rendre clair dans ce qui suit. Il faut d'abord prendre conscience d'une particularité supplémentaire de la notion du partitif, laquelle se trouve [ci-dessous](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-95027.php) (caractères gras ajoutés).

> Lorsqu'un adverbe de quantité (**assez, autant, beaucoup, davantage, moins, plus, peu, un peu, etc.**)
> apporte une précision, seule la préposition « **de/d**' » est mise entre celui-ci et le nom concerné :
>
> - J'ai bu beaucoup **d**'eau et un peu **de** vin.
> - Il me semble que j'ai bu autant **de** vin que toi, mais un peu plus **d**'eau.

« Etc. » prend en compte d'autre possibilités, comme par exemple « **si peu** », « **encore moins** », « **beaucoup plus** ».

Oui et non à la dernière remarque : à cause de « moins » on doit considérer que « de » est nécessaire, mais seulement dans le contexte d'une structure partitive ; imposer cette particule force une modification par l'adverbe « moins » qui porte sur « attention » et non sur la forme verbale idiomatique, et cela ne peut être que dans le contexte d'une *structure partitive*. Si on fait cela et donc que l'on reconnait qu'il s'agit d'une structure partitive qui a une forme spéciale à cause d'une modification par un adverbe, pour être consistent on doit reconnaitre que la structure sans modification est « prêter **de l**'attention » ou, de façon erronée (et comme vous le dite) qu'elle est « prêter **d**'attention », or ce n'est pas le cas, la structure que l'on trouve, justifiée en vertu de sa nature idiomatique, c'est « prêter attention » ou une forme pervertie, « prêter **d**'attention », ce qui n'est toujours pas une structure partitive.

On ne doit pas prendre l'usage comme preuve irrécusable  du bien fondé d'une forme linguistique ;  le fait qu'« il y a plus de résultats avec « prêter moins d'attention »», comme vous le soulignez, n'est pas une garantie que cette forme corresponde à un contexte qui se tient ; il se trouve que ce n'est pas le cas puisqu'on trouve que si l'on veut éliminer la notion de degré dans cette structure « majoritaire », c'est à dire exprimer la même chose mais sans introduire de comparaison (moins, plus, etc.), on ne trouve pas la forme qui s'indique (elle n'est pas utilisée).

Comment: Si on trouve "prêter si peu **d**'attention" et non "prêter si peu attention", il est logique de supposer que "prêter moins attention" doive s'écrire avec un "d", "moins d'", à cause de "moins". D'ailleurs, sur ngram, il y a beaucoup plus de résultats contenant "prêter moins **d**'attention". [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pr%C3%AAter+moins+attention%2Cpr%C3%AAter+moins+d%27attention&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3#)

Comment: _La forme « prêter encore moins attention » est sans aucun doute correcte et la forme avec « de » est à éviter_ --- Je le pense aussi, pourtant il y a plus de résultats avec "prêter moins **d**'attention".

Comment: @Oreste J'ai dû utiliser le champ de ma réponse pour ajouter des éclaircissements ; vous trouverez peut-être la réponse plus convaincante vu les nouvelles précisions ; si quelque chose semble faux ou non clair ne pas hésiter à commenter.

Answer (score 2):

Les deux se rencontrent.

L'expression idiomatique étant *prêter attention*, j'aurais tendance à privilégier *prêter encore moins attention* mais l'autre version ne me choque pas.

La même préposition dans la première phrase, *il ne prête pas d'attention*, me semble en revanche beaucoup moins acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

> Il écoute avec encore moins d'attention leurs discours.
>  Il écoute
> encore moins attentivement leurs discours.
>  Il prête encore moins
> attention à leurs discours.
>  Il prête encore moins d'attention à
> leurs discours même s'ils en veulent davantage et la lui rendraient au
> centuple ! [bizarre « collision »]

La locution verbale est [*prêter attention* (à quelqu'un ou quelque chose)](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/attention/6247#locution). Quand on ajoute la locution adverbiale, ce comparatif c'est *[moins](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/moins) de* ou *[moins](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/moins)... que* pour le degré encore plus faible comparativement à l'autre niveau d'attention. Mais même s'il y a dislocation de la locution prêter attention, l'adverbe ne déterminerait comme tel ni la manière de *prêter* ni la quantité d'*attention* mais la qualité ou manière de l'écoute.

D'autre part les cas où un adverbe de degré est équivalent à un déterminant/adjectif indéfini impliquent la préposition *de* (« Les œuvres les plus belles sont celles où il y a le moins de matière », au LBU14 §626 : Flaubert, *Corr.* ds. *Robert* voir *moins*). On ne voit pas comment il serait justifié de permettre au comparatif de prendre le dessus sur la locution qui l'a vu naître. Je pense que ça semble usuel vu d'autres formulations qui ne sont pas figées, par assimilation ou pour éviter de ne pas faire un autre type de liaison ou une pause mais c'est pure spéculation. À tout le moins je pense que ça explique l'hésitation...